# Cannot see Force.com perspective

Tags: force.com, force.com-ide

I installed eclipse kepler. I have jre7. I can see com.salesforce.core / api jar files in eclipse plugin folder of size around 9 MB. I can not see Force.com perspective when i do open perspective.

Comment: Have you followed [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE) link for installation of Force.com IDE in eclipse?

Comment: is full jdk needed or jre is sufficient ?

Comment: Only JRE sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed previous version of Force.com IDE 30.x instead of latest 33.x. I uninstalled new one and installed little old one. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I found and following steps 1-13 of the "Install the Force.com IDE Plug-In" instruction set on the "Force.com IDE Developer Guide" website fixed the issue (link below).

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_install.htm

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse window go to:

**Window > Open Perspective > Other**

You would see force.com as:

[image]

Select **Force.com** and click OK.

If Force.com not found then you would clean reinstall the Force.com IDE from [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE).

Comment: is full jdk needed or jre is sufficient ?

Comment: @Walker JRE is sufficient.